# Azure Table Storage - Delete Entity REST API By Partition Key

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-table-storage

Is there any way to delete an entity ONLY by PartitionKey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you really mean "Is there any way to delete all entities that have a given partition key?" The answer is no.

To delete an entity, you have to know its full identity (partition key + row key).

Comment: one approach that's been proposed for folks that regularly have this need is to put each partition in its own table. This way you can just delete the table. :)